# Spark use self reference in calculation for column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame like this one given below. Essentially it is a time series derived data frame.
My issue is that the Formula for n-th Row Col C is :-

Col(C) = (Col A(nth row) - Col A(n-1 th row)) + Col C(n-1)th row.

Hence Calculation of Col C is self referencing a previous value of Col C. I am using spark sql, can some one please advise how to proceed with this? For the calculation of Col A I am using LAG function

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems colC is just colA minus colA in the first row.

e.g.

```
1 = 6-5,
0 = 5-5,
2 = 7-5,
3 = 8-5,
-2 = 3-5
```

So this query should work:

```
SELECT colA, colA - FIRST(colA) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS colC
```

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is a cumulative sum. Here is a complete example:

```
  SELECT rowid, a, SUM(c0) OVER(ORDER BY rowid) as c
  FROM
  (
    SELECT rowid, a, a - LAG(a, 1) OVER(ORDER BY rowid) as c0
    FROM
    (
      SELECT 1 as rowid, 5 as a union all
      SELECT 2 as rowid, 6 as a union all
      SELECT 3 as rowid, 5 as a union all
      SELECT 4 as rowid, 7 as a union all
      SELECT 5 as rowid, 8 as a union all
      SELECT 6 as rowid, 3 as a
    )t
  )t
```

Comment: I understand this but the value of Col C is self referenced, this is the issue I am facing

Comment: Looks like you need a cumulative sum, I've updated the answer

Comment: I have simplified the question. My bad if it wasnt correct in the first go. I need c(n) = a(n) - a(n-1) + c(n-1)

Comment: Added a complete example for your case